# Can I develop a SharePoint 2010 Service Application using .NET 4 or 4.5?

Tags: 2010, service-application, .net

Since SharePoint 2010 Service Applications are abstracted out, is there any way to develop Service Applications using the .NET 4.0 or 4.5?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you can, for example, create a WCF service application using .NET 4.0 or 4.5 and consume that WCF service application in your SP code (SP 2010 Service Application) or even from InfoPath forms or Java...